# custom textview doesn't fill parent

Tags: android, textview, android-custom-view

I'm getting in trouble with a custom textview.
I created the custom view and it is fine but now i'm trying to center it in parent with:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal = true
```

but it doesn't center in parent, it doesn't even take all the space available even if i set a

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
```

This is my code for the Custom Textview:

```
public class GlowTextView extends TextView{

private Context context;
private AttributeSet attr;

private static final String COLOR = "#9bdb9d";
private static final String SHADOW_COLOR = "#26db2b";

public String ora = "00:00"; //il testo che verra' disegnato

/*handler per il ritardo dell' orologio*/
Handler handler = new Handler();

/*Calendar per il recupero dell' ora*/
private Calendar calendar;

private Paint paint = new Paint();

public GlowTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    this.context = context;

    handler.post(sendData); //faccio partire il timer per l' ora
}

public GlowTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    this.context = context;
    this.attr = attrs;

    handler.post(sendData);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    setText(ora);
    //setTextSize(size); //grandezza del testo
    setTextColor(Color.parseColor(COLOR));
    setShadowLayer(15, 0, 0, Color.parseColor(SHADOW_COLOR));
    setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Neon.ttf")); //font per l' ora
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int reqWidth;
    int reqHeight;


    reqWidth = (int)(ora.length() * this.getTextSize());
    reqHeight = (int) this.getTextSize();

    // set the calculated width and height of your drawing area
    setMeasuredDimension(reqWidth, reqHeight);
}

private void setClockText(String text) {
    setText(text);
    invalidate();
}

/*
 * delay per l' aggiornamento dell' orologio
 */
private final Runnable sendData = new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        try {
            /*Recuper l' ora*/
            calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            String minute = Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            if(minute.length() == 1) minute = '0' + minute;
            String hour = Integer.toString(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
            if(hour.length() == 1) hour = '0' + hour;

            ora = hour + ":" + minute;

            /*Passo l' ora alla textview
             */
            setClockText(ora);

            Log.d("Delay", "Refresh clock!");
            handler.postDelayed(this, 15000);    
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
};
}
```

Comment: Do you even need to override onMeasure in your case? If you didn't override onMeasure, what would your problem be?

Comment: if i didn't override it the problem is the same the textview doesn't get centered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adjusting the gravity of the layout

**If your TextView has layout_width="match_parent"**:

```
    <package.name.customTextView
        android:id="@+id/myCustomTextView"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        ...
```

**If your textView has layout_width="wrap_content"**

```
    <package.name.customTextView
        android:id="@+id/myCustomTextView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        ...
```

Hope this helps, happy coding!